# Is there a way to run a single job instance across multiple workers in fastapi

Tags: fastapi, jobs

I am using apscheduler to create background jobs to run in my fastapi application, however when I start the application with more than one worker the job is duplicated across the workers resulting in all kinds of error and potentially security flaws.

here is a simplified example

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler
from fastapi import BackgroundTasks, FastAPI

def some_job():
    print ("hello world")

app = FastAPI()
shed = AsyncIOScheduler()

shed.add_job(some_job, "interval", seconds=5)


@app.get("/test")
async def test():
    return {"Hello":"world"}

shed.start()
```

and to run it use `uvicorn main:app --workers 4`

this will result in `hello world` being printed 4 times every time the job is triggered.

Is there a way to call one instances across all the jobs (on the parent process level)?

I research some solutions online but most of them use celery and similar modules or lock files and memory locations but both options are too complicated and I prefer to use the minimum number of modules

Comment: Do you need to run the scheduler and and FastAPI in the same process? Unless you're doing something special, I would separate `shed.start()` to inside `if __name__ == "__main__":` in another python file (e.g. `run_scheduler.py`), and then start that separately from `uvicorn`.

Comment: @M.O. could you elaborate more on how you would achieve such thing

Comment: I'll write it in an answer, one sec

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could run the scheduler in the parent process and the fastapi in a sperate child process by using python's multiprocessing

```
import multiprocessing
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()
@app.get("/")
async def home():
    return {"Hello":"world"}

def regular_function():
    print("Hello world")

def run_app():
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, workers=4)

def main():
    app_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=run_app)
    app_process.start()

    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(regular_function, 'interval', seconds=5, max_instances=1) 
    scheduler.start()

    app_process.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Implementing it like this, I am getting this error.

```OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor ```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to not run your scheduler in the same process as FastAPI, but as two different processes. Something like:

```py
# main.py
from fastapi import BackgroundTasks, FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/test")
async def test():
    return {"Hello":"world"}
```

```py
# scheduler.py
import asyncio

from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler

def some_job():
    print ("hello world")

shed = AsyncIOScheduler()
shed.add_job(some_job, "interval", seconds=5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        pass
```

and in one terminal run `uvicorn main:app --workers 4`, and in another `python scheduler.py`.

Comment: isn't there a way to run them in the same process?

Comment: There might very well be, this was just the simplest solution I could think of.